# Typescript compile error missing line number information

Tags: gruntjs, typescript

Typescript compiler does not always display line number or any contextual information about where an error has occurred. Especially when the error has occurred in another file which was compiled as part of process of compiling current file.

Is there a way to fix this?

Example:

```
// this is inside test.ts file
import * as Info from './infomodule';
```

if you compile `test.ts` and there is an error in `infomodule.ts` then usually `tsc` just gives your the error without any contextual information. Something like this:

```
Running "typescript:watch" (typescript) task

>>   Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'IDriverChartsDriverInfo'.
Warning: Task "typescript:watch" failed. Use --force to continue.
```

(I am using a grunt task to compile typescript files)

Answer (score 0):

> then usually tsc

This isn't `tsc` this is `grunt-typescript`. Report this as a bug here : https://github.com/k-maru/grunt-typescript